# Python nested dictionary and list concatnate dictionary keys with list values

Tags: python

I have a nested dict as follows:

```
list = { "A" : [ "1", "2", "3" ], "B" :  [ "2" ], "C" : [ "1", "2" ] }
```

I want to concatenate dictionary keys and list values as follows:

```
[ "A.1", "A.2", "A.3", "B.2", "C.1", "C.2" ]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried Floris?

Comment: @ChristianDean I had tried almost exactly what Alex Hall is showing below but had omitted the second "for val in vals" part, makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = {"A": ["1", "2", "3"], "B": ["2"], "C": ["1", "2"]}
result = ["{}.{}".format(key, val)
          for key, vals in lst.items()
          for val in vals]
print(result)
```

Comment: Why not put the comp all on one line?

Comment: @ChristianDean because I find this more readable, and using as few lines as possible is not a good goal.

Comment: I'd have to disagree @Alex Hall. I think short, concise, and _readable_ code is what one _should_ aim for. One should try to avoid overly verbose code, as long as the code stays readable. Of course, your objection is that `["{}.{}".format(key, val) for key, vals in lst.items() for val in vals]` _isn't_ readable. I think it is, but if you disagree, that's fair enough. Nice answer, +1.

Comment: [Google's Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#List_Comprehensions) would say this is a no go: break it out into a proper loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following code:

```
list = { "A" : [ "1", "2", "3" ], "B" :  [ "2" ], "C" : [ "1", "2" ] }
data = []
for key, values in list.items():
    for value in values:
        data.append("{0}.{1}".format(key,value))
print(data)
# Output ['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'B.2', 'C.1', 'C.2']
```

Comment: This would benefit from improving the variable names: `for x in v:` is much less readable than `for value in values:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = []
for ks, vs in list.items():
    for v in vs:
        new_list.append('.'.join([ks, v]))

print(new_list)
# output
['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'B.2']
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a loop with the pair values of the dictionary and append each individual value in the empty list.